# ASP.NET membership returning DateTime with Kind set to Local

Tags: .net, datetime, utc

I have an MVC3 project using ASP.NET default membership provider. I am trying to show the details of a user on a View page. When I do

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(id);
```

to get the user I am about to display, all of the DateTimes (CreationDate, LastActivityDate) have the Kind property set to Local.

All of these dates are saved in the SQL Server database in UTC time, so why are they coming into MVC as Local? It is messing up my time zone conversions because I expect the server times to be in UTC.

Is there something you can set so that the user returned from the GetUser function will have DateTimes in DateTimeKind.Utc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `myDate.ToUniversalTime()`

If you mean that the value in your DateTime is actually the UTC time, but the kind is set to Local, then you will have to convert it to UTC.

```
var myUtcDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(myDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Unfortunately, this is a general problem with the .NET DateTime class and SQL, not anything specific to MVC.  I don't know of any way to get the DateTime in UTC format with DateTimeKind.Utc set.

You may want to read John Skeets rant about DateTime.

http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html

If you need to use this frequently, one option would be to create an extension method to do this.

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions {
    public static DateTime MakeUtcKind(this DateTime dateTime) {
        return DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }
}
```

Then you can simply do this:

```
var createDate = Membership.GetUser(id).CreationDate.MakeUtcKind();
```

Comment: That would actually convert his already UTC-time to UTC time again, and mess up his date conversions

Comment: @Kenneth - Maybe I misunderstood, but he seems to be complaining that he's getting his time in LocalTime rather than in UTC.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that too. I think the value is actually UTC, but the kind is Local. So I think what he's asking is, how can change the kind without affecting the value? Anyway, some clarification from the OP might be needed.

Comment: Hm, perfect! I actually had to look up `SpecifyKind`. I was under the impression that it actually converted the value as well. I was wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The time is the correct UTC value, but the Kind is set to Local so when I try to convert it I get errors. The first thing I tried was to set the kind myself 
`MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(id);
user.CreationDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(user.CreationDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);` but that won't even compile because the CreateDate is read only.

Comment: @zmar - you can't change it in the membership user.  You have to get the date from the membership user into a local variable, change the kind, then use the local variable.

Comment: Well, I wanted it set correctly so I could use a strongly typed View of the user. I guess I can use a workaround and set the dates in the ViewBag for the View to display. Thanks!!

Comment: @zmar - Your other option is to store the time as the correctly local time, then convert to UTC.